# R merge question: How to perform 1:1 similar to Stata?

Tags: r, merge, stata

Lets say I have these two tables:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Symbol = c("A", "A", "B"),
  Quant = c(10, 10, 10),
  ID1 = c(1, 2, 3)
)
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Symbol = c("A", "B", "A"),
  Quant = c(10, 10, 10),
  ID2 = c(4, 5, 6)
)
```

I want to merge these two tables using Symbol and Quant as keys so that I get 1 to 1 match for each rows.

I tried inner, outer, left, right, and other kinds of joins mentioned in dplyr package but did not get my desired result.

My desired result would be:

| Symbol | Quant | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 | 4 |
| A | 10 | 2 | 6 |
| B | 10 | 3 | 5 |

Comment: Why is it 4, 6, 5, and not 6, 4, 5?

Comment: The mention in the title "similar to Stata" is not especially helpful here. Stata offers several ways to `merge` and although what you want to do is supported -- if users insist -- it is not especially good practice. (I am very positive about Stata, but just think that this question would be improved by focusing entirely and explicitly on what you want to do in R.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be implicitly joining on the sequence in which the rows of a group appear. If you make that explicit, it will be easier to join. Here's a helper function for that to add a sequence per group

```
add_seq <- function(df, var) {
  mutate(df, seq=1:n(), .by={{var}})
}
```

And then you can use that with each of the tables and perform the join

```
add_seq(df1, c(Symbol, Quant)) %>% 
  left_join(add_seq(df2, c(Symbol, Quant))) %>% 
  select(-seq)
Joining with `by = join_by(Symbol, Quant, seq)`
#   Symbol Quant ID1 ID2
# 1      A    10   1   4
# 2      A    10   2   6
# 3      B    10   3   5
```

Comment: This code is giving me error. Error is fixed when I only use 1 variable to match. But I need to match them using 2 keys

Comment: This example uses two variables for matching (Symbol and Quant). Can you provide an example that doesn't work?

Comment: I updated the R and dplyr and it is working now. Thank you

Comment: I updated the R and dplyr and it is working now. Thank you

Comment: I updated the R and dplyr and it is working now. Thank you